# make the header of a div sticky, and take up the width of the div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to make the header inside of a div with a list sticky or fixed position, but it only sticks to the width of the text and if I expand the width to 100% it takes the size of the page:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const ScrollableContainer = styled.div`
overflow-y: visible;
overflow-x: hidden;
height: 700px;
text-align: left;
justify-content: space-between;
cursor: auto;
`;

const TableHeader = styled.header`
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
background-color: white;
z-index: 9;
line-height: 40px;
`;
export const TestView= () => {
     return (       
<ScrollableContainer>
            <TableHeader>
                Text here
            </TableHeader>
// some list goes 
       </ScrollableContainer >
)
};
```

I cannot pragmatically set the width to a value, since the div has to adjust to the screensize.

Comment: What about `position: sticky`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: try setting the parent position to 'position: relative'

Comment: thank you, position sticky to the header doesn't work, and position: relative to the parent div stretches the width of the header to the page width, so unfortunately it doesn't fit in the div box

Answer (score 1):

Position fixed will mean its position is relative to the viewport. Setting its width to 100% will indeed make it as wide as the viewport (the entire page).

You can set the `position: inherit;` to inherit its parents width.

```
const TableHeader = styled.header`
position: fixed;
width: inherit;
height: 40px;
background-color: white;
z-index: 9;
line-height: 40px;
`;
```